# Resolving maven dependencies at runtime during plugin execution

Tags: java, maven, plugins, maven-plugin, mojo

I have a maven plugin that checks some dependencies. Those dependencies at unknown at first, so I can't add them to the pom file. Thus, I need a way to resolve dependencies at runtime during the plugin execution given the artifactId and the groupId.

There's a lack of proper documentation on the goal we are trying to achieve.

Comment: What is the idea behind this? How could a dependency be either on the disk or remote? Could you give us more background?

Comment: Sorry [J Fabian Meier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/927493/j-fabian-meier), I fixed my question. The dependencies I need to resolve are not known at first, so I need a way to resolve dependencies at runtime during the plugin execution given the artifactId and the groupId.

Comment: Where do these dependencies come from, if they are not know before?

Comment: I suspect you have a main program which calls interfaces and want to provide various implementations during runtime. There are two way to achieve this. The manual approach is to copy the runtime dependencies to your disk and pass them to the class path. The automatic approach would be to create Maven projects for each of your implementations bundling your main JAR alongside with a single implementation.

Comment: @Karsten In the context of Maven plugins, you would ask the user to add the appropriate dependencies to the plugin in the plugin declaration (in the POM).

Comment: @J Fabian Meier Then I didn't understand the question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Maven resolver API.

Example code of maven plugin in Resolver project:

https://github.com/apache/maven-resolver/blob/master/maven-resolver-demos/maven-resolver-demo-maven-plugin/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/resolver/examples/maven/ResolveArtifactMojo.java